# CDF format - disable cell selection?

Tags: notebooks, options, cdf-format, cells

Is there any way/option in order to make `Cells` not selectable in exported *CDF* files?

I know how to hide the cells until you go with the mouse over them on the right edge of the document (go to `Palettes->Writing assistant->Writing and formatting->Notebook properties and actions->Content->Cell Brackets: Show/Hide`). But I want that these are actually not selectable by the user, or even better, that the cell brackets don't appear in any form. I remember some option dark in my head but I have not been able to find it, or I just went a little bit crazy and there is not such an option.

**EDIT 1**: it would be great to know how to change this setting also on already created notebooks, and not to have to edit each cell of a big notebook manually.

**EDIT 2**: I decided to accept Edmund's answer since at least with that you are able to hide the cells. Careful, you are still able to SELECT the cells, so cdf programs will still crush sometimes.

**EDIT 3**: At the end, Kuba's suggestion solved my problem, see also the comment. For me `CDFDeploy["notebook.cdf", 
 EvaluationNotebook[], Method -> "Standalone", Deployed -> True]` works on the tablets and large display tv's I have tested until now.

**Background**: I am creating some content for students and they use the cdf files in tablets. If you want to scroll down, you wont be able to scroll with the 2 finger touch gesture, so you have to use the scroll bar on the right edge. Sadly, any normal person will then accidentally touch the cell brackets and select some interactive content. This causes sometimes a crush of the cdf and it has to be killed and restarted, which is very annoying.

Comment: Take a look at available Cell options, e.g. `ShowCellBracket`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is this also applicable somehow to all cells of a notebook? By that I mean, for a notebook, already created. Or do I have to edit each cell again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set some options on a notebook level. Related to editing options are `Editable` and `Selectable` too. Or `Deployed` which combines them:

```
CreateDocument[{x + y, 1/x + 1/y},
   ShowCellBracket -> False,
   Deployed -> True
]
```

so you can also do this for existing notebooks:

```
SetOptions[ notebookObject, Deployed->True,...]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Since I like the Standalone style, in the end I used your advice with `CDFDeploy["notebook.cdf", 
 EvaluationNotebook[], Method -> "Standalone", Deployed -> True]` , which looks nice and solves the problem on the large display tv.

Answer (score 1):

To hide cell brackets in a notebook you can use `SetOptions` and `Cells`.

```
SetOptions[#, ShowCellBracket -> False] & /@ Cells[];
```

`Cells` returns all of the cells in the `EvaluationNotebook`. `SetOptions` sets the `ShowCellBracket` option to `False`.

You can re-enable them with

```
SetOptions[#, ShowCellBracket -> True] & /@ Cells[];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: hmmm.... I just tested a cdf file on a large format screen with touch functionality and it still crushes. May be this is due to fact, that cell brackets can only be "hidden" but still you are able to select them. Still thanks, I think the option I want (no cell brackets / not selectable) is just not possible.

Comment: @MauricioLobos `SetOptions[#, ShowCellBracket -> False, Selectable -> False] & /@ 
  Cells[];`.  Since this makes all the cells not selectable you have to insert a new cell to set everything back to `True`. I think you can select all the notebook cells and do this through the _Option Inspector_.